# Java: JFrame Graphics not drawing rectangle

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

Hello fellow programmers,

I've ran into a little issue in my code that I can't seem to crack. It has to do with the Jframe; Graphics area of Java. The code that I'll post below, is over a drawing method. Which purpose is to draw the "rooms" that are in a *ArrayList* `roomList` which is located in another class hence `lvl.` before. This off-course doesn't happen, hence the post on here.

```
public class LevelGUI implements Observer {

    private Level lv;
    private Display d;
    
    public LevelGUI(Level level, String name) {

        this.lv = level;
        
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(name);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        d = new Display(lv, 500, 500);
        frame.getContentPane().add(d);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocation(0, 0);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    private class Display extends JPanel {

        public Display(Level fp, int x, int y) {
            addKeyListener(new Listener());
            setBackground(Color.GRAY);
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(x + 20, y + 20));
            setFocusable(true);
        }
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            draw(g);
        }
        private void draw(Graphics g) {
            Level lvl = new Level();
            for(int i = 0; i < lvl.roomList.size(); i++) {
                Room room = lvl.roomList.get(i);
                g.setColor(room.floorColor);
                g.drawRect(room.posX, room.posY, room.roomWidth, room.roomHeight);
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

**To get some background info on the program**. `roomList` is the *ArrayList*, and it is filled with various different sized and colored rooms. The rooms themselves are *objects*.

Here comes first `Level` *class*:

```
public class Level extends Observable {

    private boolean Switch = true;

    public ArrayList<Room> roomList = new ArrayList<Room>(); 

    (...)
}
```

Here is the *Class* `Room()` that is used to create the rooms.

```
public class Room {
    Color floorColor;
    int roomWidth;
    int roomHeight;
    int posX;
    int posY;

    public Room(int dx, int dy, Color color) {
        this.floorColor = color;
        this.roomHeight = dy;
        this.roomWidth = dx;
        this.posY = 0;
        this.posX = 0;
    }

    (...)
}
```

I've managed to locate where the problem is thought to occur, and it's the code in the *for-loop*. I tried switching the `roomList.size()` for an *integer* to test if it was the loop., But it wasn't. It is possible to draw a figure outside of the *for-loop*.

and again, **the problem** isn't an error message, the program simply doesn't draw the rooms that I've instructed it to draw in the *method* `draw()`.

The display output looks like this:
[image]

Thanks beforehand!

Comment: Ok, I'll add them to the question, hold on a minute please.

Comment: Can you paste the actual code and not an image of the code.

Comment: Where are you calling `draw` from? Is it being called from a paintComponent method of a swing component? Is that component added to a layout and visible. Does it have a size?

Comment: @matt ok hold on, I'll do that instead.

Comment: @matt it is being called from ```paintComponent()```

Comment: There we go. Added the needed code, removed some unnecessary code, and pasted in the actual code instead of picture.

Comment: How do you know the draw method is invoked? How do you know the for loop is executed? How do you know the panel is added to the frame? How do you know what the size of the panel is? Maybe the size is (0, 0) so there is nothing to paint. We don't have enough information to suggest a fix since we don't know the context of how that code is invoked.. Post a proper [mre] when asking a question. See [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for two ways to draw coloured rectangle on a panel.

Comment: @camickr you took the words out of my fingers!

Comment: @camickr now I've added the full necessary classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be aware that the paintComponent() method is invoked by Swing whenever the framework thinks the component needs to be rendered on screen. This usually is when the window is getting visible - initially or because some other window no longer hides the component. Such events are out of your control.

So your application should create a state and be ready to draw it anytime. Therefore you do not create state (like a level) inside the paint() or paintComponent() method. Put that elsewhere - if need be into the constructor.

Looking at you code:
As you are creating a new level inside paintComponent()/draw(), is it correct to assume that this level has no rooms associated? In that case the method is right to return without having painted anything.

If your application thinks the screen should be updated call repaint(), knowing that the paint() method will be called by the framework soon.

Comment: (1+) *Therefore you do not create state (like a level) inside the paint() or paintComponent() method.* - good catch, I missed that one.

Comment: I figured it out when you wrote: "Looking at you code: As you are creating a new level inside paintComponent()/draw()..." I created a new level which didn't have the rooms saved.